# How to reinstall windows on a Allview wi8g(windows tablet)?

Tags: windows-10, tablet

I found this tablet and it had windows 10 and the drivers where really bad. I wanted to give aa factory reset but got stuck at 66% and then error,i tried again but stuck at 66% i said i stop then i will install a new windows but now my tablet boot but when it gets to windows the screen stay black and i see just a part of my cursor that i can move in the darkness. Now i want to try to reinstall the windows maybe it will solve the problem but i can't make the tablet

Comment: Contact the manufacturer. They should be able to provide some kind of recovery image and instructions. It appears that this was originally a Windows 8 tablet. https://www.allviewmobile.com/index.php/wi8g.html

Comment: i would do this but they will tell me to send the tablet to their service but i don't want this.

Comment: And they don't give drivers or anything for the tablet cause they are confidential.